# No HTML tag escaping in Rails XML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I want to display some HTML in a XML view file (RSS) in rails:

```
# ...
xml.description raw("<![CDATA[ "+raw(news.content(@language).body)+"]]>")
# ...
```

This generates the following ...

```
<description type="html">&amp;lt;![CDATA[ &amp;amp;lt;p&amp;amp;gt; ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Rails v3? Replace raw(stuff) with stuff.html_safe

Comment: Yes, Rails3. But String.html_safe does not work :(

Answer (score 4):

After messing around with `#raw` and `#html_safe`, I found this to be working:

```
# ...
xml.description do
  xml.cdata! news.content(@language).body
end
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. html_safe should work. Maybe this will help you? http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/